# Laravel: form action and routing error. Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: {id}]

Tags: laravel-5

URL: http://drpinoy.me/1

controller

```
public function show($id) {
    $fields = Field::all();
    $doctor = DB::table('doctors')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    return view('frontend.pages.single')
        ->with('fields', $fields)
        ->with('doctor', $doctor);
}
public function reviews(Request $request,$id) {
    return 'hello';
}
```

single.blade.php

```
<div class="reviews">
    {!! Form::open(['action'=>['FrontendController@reviews', $doctor->id], 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Full Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Full Name']) }}
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}
                {{ Form::text('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email Address']) }}
            </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('message', 'Message') }}
            {{ Form::message('message', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'achievements', 'placeholder' => 'Message']) }}
        </div>
        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

route:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'FrontendController@show');
Route::post('/{id}', 'FrontendController@reviews');
```

Greetings, i need help,i have a single page with url drpinoy.me/1, i added a form in that page, but couldnt get through with the routes error. im newbie, need advice. thank you so much..

Comment: For test, add static id on form Replace $doctor->id with any number and remove other content of the form and then try to submit

Comment: Hi @DsRaj it works when i replaced the $doctor->id, and remove the content, but with the content, it returns an error, ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method message does not exist.

Comment: replace this with text 'Form::message('

Comment: WOW!!! spent so many hours only the html tags, thank you so much @DsRaj

Comment: Glad it helps, Mark the answer for other users. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very first add a static id and then try to submit the form also there is one issue on form remove the message as there is no message option in the blade

```
{{ Form::message('message', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'achievements', 'placeholder' => 'Message']) }}
```

replace this message with text

```
{{ Form::text('message', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'achievements', 'placeholder' => 'Message']) }}
```